# Droid2600 (Android Atari 2600 emulator) runtime error

Tags: android, emulation, sdl

After I compile the [sources](http://code.google.com/p/droid2600/), launch the app, and try starting a game (ROM), the app crashes. If I install the [apk](http://code.google.com/p/droid2600/downloads/list) rather than compile one myself, and try running the same ROM, everything works fine. What could I possibly do wrong? Here's the error I'm getting:

```
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library sdl not found
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at com.droid2600.LoadLibrary.<init>(Globals.java:41)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at com.droid2600.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-25 13:19:52.170: E/AndroidRuntime(7878):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I bet it's that whole missing library thing.

Comment: Yes, as Dave Newton says, you didn't package the library.  If the java package name of the library functions will be unchanged in your build, you can try extracting the compiled .so from the available .apk by opening it as a zip file, then moving it (or them if it's mutliple-abi) into the project tree.  Or you can build libsdl from android-ified sources using the ndk.  You may well have to download those sources separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Dave and Chris for your tips, you were both right, I totally forgot about NDK. If anyone stumbles upon this exact problem: it's much easier to just take the .so files from an existing .apk than compile those Stella sources, trust me.